# SocketException while reading data from Request.Body in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sockets, azure-service-fabric, socketexception

We recently migrated one project from [Azure Cloud Services (classic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me) to Service Fabric. It is a ASP.NET WebAPI. Since then we are getting a lot of `SocketException` in the **Deserialize** method . The code looks like:

```
using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(Request.Body, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(decompressionStream))
    {
        // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            model= Serializer.Deserialize<Model>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is:

```
Message:
 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Sometime we get:

```
The read operation failed, see inner exception. One or more errors occurred. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Exception Stack:

```
System.IO.IOException:
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1+FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.AdaptedPipeline+<ReadInputAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody+<PumpAsync>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody+<ReadAsync>d__27.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__21.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.Read (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteToken (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteToken (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateJToken (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Controller.Post (Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: F:\Controller.cs:80)
Inner exception System.AggregateException handled at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.RawStream.EndRead (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback (System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
Inner exception Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.RawStream+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection+<ProcessReceives>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection+<DoReceive>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

Earlier the code in Classic Service used to be like this and used to work fine:

```
Model model;
try
{
    using (var sr = await OpenDecompressedBodyAsync(request.Content))
    {
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            model = Serializer.Deserialize<Model>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}

private async Task<StreamReader> OpenDecompressedBodyAsync(HttpContent requestContent)
        {
            var body = await requestContent.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var gzip = new GZipStream(body, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            var sr = new StreamReader(gzip);
            return sr;
        }
```

We have tried a lot of things, however, the exception still exists. Also, it is not too common. Happens once in a while. The data volume is very high and each Request.Body can have upto 2-3MB of data. Can someone help why we are getting SocketException?

Comment: What do you mean is that after the migration, your program can work normally, but occasionally this SocketException will appear?

Comment: You can fire up [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see exactly what is happening on the wire to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @JasonPan, yes. For example, in the last 24hrs there has been 5.35M request and only 244 SocketException

Comment: It could be a client disconnect happening in those cases. (user navigates away, closes tabs, programmatically cancels the upload, etc.)

Comment: @LoekD It is a API call from a publisher system. No user interacting with the system directly.

Comment: Network issues still occur.

Answer (score 0):

*Try to disable firewall/antivirus, and test.*

If it works. it means you need to allow specific port or create a new rule for this.

Comment: As it is always running in Production system handling 5M+ calls per day and rare socket exceptions, we cannot ask admin to turn off firewall/antivirus for a few days to test. The risk is far more in this case. Will not be approved.